# Crystal reports in VB6 application on Windows 7 64-bit

Tags: sql-server, windows-7, vb6, crystal-reports

We're able to install our VB6 application on Windows 7 64-bit, but it won't display any reports (Crystal Reports). The message is

> CrystralReport 20599
>   Cannot open SQL server.

How do we fix it?

Answer (score 1):

One possible solution:

1. Remove from control panel your sql server odbc-connection.
2. Insert a new one using odbcad32.exe.

Yesterday I was able to get old software to function again, using this. The odbc system is quite different in 64-bit environment than 32-bit.

Answer (score 0):

I am able to mark the issue, it's a DSN driver problem. you can try to User DSN instead of System DSN.

My development environment is :---
-Windows-7
-VB6
-Crystal Report 8
-MS Access (.mdb)